# removing double quote from json.dumps of string data

Tags: python, json

I have some data that I'm retrieving from a data feed as text.  For example, I receive the data like the following:

```
1105488000000, 34.1300, 34.5750, 32.0700, 32.2800\r\n
1105574400000, 32.6750, 32.9500, 31.6500, 32.7300\r\n
1105660800000, 36.8250, 37.2100, 34.8650, 34.9000\r\n
```

etc.

(This is stock data, where the first column is the timestamp, the next columns are the open, high, low, and close price for the time period.)

I want to convert this into a json such as the following:

```
[
[1105488000000, 34.1300, 34.5750, 32.0700, 32.2800], 
[1105574400000, 32.6750, 32.9500, 31.6500, 32.7300], 
[1105660800000, 36.8250, 37.2100, 34.8650, 34.9000],
...
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
  lines = data.split("\r\n");
  output = []
  for line in lines:
     currentLine = line.split(",")
     currentLine = [currentLine[0] , currentLine[1] , currentLine[2], currentLine[3], currentLine[4]]
     output.append(currentLine)


  jsonOutput = json.dumps(output)
```

However, when I do this, I'm finding that the values are:

```
[
["1105488000000", "34.1300", "34.5750", "32.0700", "32.2800"], 
["1105574400000", "32.6750", "32.9500", "31.6500", "32.7300"], 
["1105660800000", "36.8250", "37.2100", "34.8650", "34.9000"],
```

Is there anyway for me to get the output without the double quotes?

Comment: That's because you're inserting strings into the array rather than inserting numerics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the data through the `int()` or `float()` constructors before outputting in order to turn them into **numbers**.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, and my results have decimal issues such as:

[1105488000000, 34.130000000000003, 34.579999999999998, 32.07, 32.280000000000001]

I tried using round, but that doesn't appear to work.  I did a search for Decimal, but json appears to not be able to serialize Decimal.

Comment: Yes, welcome to IEEE 754 floating point numbers, where there are very few exact values.

Comment: Do I have any other alternatives?  Or is the JSON library not suitable for me, and I have to build the JSON myself?

Comment: You could write your own [encoder](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) that specializes a little bit, or even handles `Decimal` appropriately.

Comment: I think specializing it will have to be the route that I go.  Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

```
...
currentLine = [float(i) for i in currentLine]
output.append(currentLine)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
currentLine = [currentLine[0] , currentLine[1] , currentLine[2], currentLine[3], currentLine[4]]
output.append(currentLine)
```

to

```
currentData = map(lambda num: float(num.strip()) , currentLine)
output.append(currentData)
```

Whenever you initialize `currentLine` with

```
currentLine = line.split(",")
```

all the elements of `currentLine` are strings.  So, whenever you write this to JSON, you get JSON strings throughout.  By converting all the strings to numbers, you get something without quotes.  Also, I added the `strip()` calls to handle leading and trailing whitespace as is shown in your data example.

P.S. Please don't use the same variable name for two completely different things.  It's more clear to use `currentLine` for the list of strings, and `currentData` for the list of numbers.

Comment: [`map`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools) could be very useful here.

Comment: @sarnold map was my first instinct as well, but I am cautious about using map whenever my output data must have a certain size but my input data may be larger.  That said, the data sample in the question is always 5 numbers per line, so I modified my answer to use map.

Comment: Heh, [kev's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9577022/377270) is cleaner still; I mostly used Python before the list comprehensions were introduced, so they're still at the back of my mind.

Comment: Thanks.  I noted above that when I tried to convert the string to a decimal, I get values such as [1105488000000, 34.130000000000003, 34.579999999999998, 32.07, 32.280000000000001].  I'm unfamiliar with map, and lambda (still a python newbie) so I will look that up.  Do you think it will produce a value different from using just a straight float conversion?

Comment: Map and lambdas aren't going to change the actual conversion, which is problematic here (and in any programming language I've ever used) because computers represent numbers in binary and can't represent some numbers exactly, just as we can't represent one-third exactly in base 10.  Python supports true decimal numbers that play nicely with base-10 fractions, but the `json.dumps` function seems to be unable to handle them.  In short, my answer is functionally equivalent to kev's answer.

Comment: I think I will have to do what Ignacio recommends and try to specialize an encoder in order to cleanly handle this data.  By converting to float, it blows out the amount of data I'm returning, unfortunately.  Thanks for your answer, though.